# Need help - SoapUi testRunner.getStatus() is returning the status as "RUNNING" indefinitely

Tags: groovy, soapui

In SoapUI after executing a soap request test step (which is under a test suite -> test case)
through **[testRunner.runTestStepByName](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestCaseRunner.html#runTestStepByName%28java.lang.String%29)**("*Soap Request Name*")

and waiting for 10 seconds after that soap request execution [testRunner.getStatus()](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestRunner.html#getStatus%28%29) is returning **RUNNING** status . below is the groovy script (which is under same test suite -> test case)

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status

testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetCitiesByCountry - Request 1")
sleep(10000)
log.info( "...${testRunner.getStatus()}...")

while ( testRunner.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING ) {
    log.info(testRunner.getStatus())
}
```

the output is below

```
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
Wed Apr 17 21:06:22 IST 2013:INFO:RUNNING
.
.
continuing for infinite time...
```

*Ideally it should return* **FINISHED** *since the above test step is executed* ,

Advanced thanks for any help to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds logical, as long as you are in the loop, the test is 'running'. You can get the status with this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStepResult.TestStepStatus
myTestStepResult = testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetCitiesByCountry - Request 1")
myStatus = myTestStepResult.getStatus()
if (myStatus == TestStepStatus.OK)
log.info "The step status is: " + myStatus.toString()
else
log.error "The step status is: " + myStatus.toString()
```

Also, as the call to runTestStepByName is synchronous, there is no 'running' status, only 'CANCELED', 'FAILED', 'OK' or 'UNKNOWN'.

[See the doc here](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStepResult.TestStepStatus.html)

Comment: thanks @gaelperret ... but with above code the soapui showing the i value is 0 .. so for testRunner.results[i-1].status.... its giving "Array Index outof bound Exception:negative array index[-1]..." . so still get stuck with the same issue .

Comment: @uday035, you are right, the above code works only if the step you run with 'runTestStepByName' is right before the current step. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @gaelperret, according to the [latest documentation](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStepResult.TestStepStatus.html) there is no property `TestStepStatus.CANCEL`, only `TestStepStatus.CANCELED`